# htaccess Rewrite URL with 4 GET parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem when rewriting URL using .htaccess.

it works fine with **3 GET parameters.**

**test.com/account/activation/id123**

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^account$ account.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^account/([^./]+)$ account.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^account/([^./]+)/([^./]+)$ account.php?id=$1&activation=$2 [NC,L]
```

until i try **add another** parameters.

```
RewriteRule ^account/([^./]+)/([^./]+)$ account.php?id=$1&activation=$2&re=$3 [NC,L]
```

**test.com/account/activation/id123/taken**

it's not working. it goes to 404 not found page.

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is still accepting 2 patterns. You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^account/?$ account.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^account/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^account/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?id=$1&activation=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^account/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?id=$1&activation=$2&re=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks anubhava for answering, but it still not working. it goes to 404 not found.

Comment: Is this the full URL causing 404 `http://test.com/account/activation/id123/taken` ?

Comment: my bad, i forget to copy RewriteRule ^ - [L] it's working right now! YOU ARE AWESOME anubhava!!!!